# Vocab learning program not working properly

Tags: java

So this is the code, and it's meant to give a random word from a list, have the user input the meaning that's in an external text file, and if it's correct, it removes the word from the list otherwise it keeps the word and adds it to a missedWord list. The problem is that the words aren't getting removed from the list, and I can't seem to print the ArrayList. Can anyone help me with this problem? Also, are there any improvements I can make to the code? Thank you for all of your help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordList1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    boolean fart = true;

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("WL1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList wordArray = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList missedWords = new ArrayList();

    String input, stringArray[] = new String[2], answer;

    while((input=br.readLine())!=null){
        stringArray = input.split(" ");
        wordArray.add(stringArray);
    }

    while(fart){
        stringArray = (String[]) wordArray.get((int)(Math.random()*(wordArray.size())));
        System.out.println(stringArray[0]);
        answer = console.nextLine();
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[1])){
            System.out.println("CORRECT");
            wordArray.remove(stringArray[1]);
        }
        if(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[1])){
            System.out.println("INCORRECT, " + stringArray[1]);
            missedWords.add(stringArray[0]);
        }
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("escape")){
            fart = false;
            System.out.println(missedWords);
        }
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("print"))
            System.out.println(wordArray);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: your program seems to suffer from a bit of flatulence..

Comment: I think `crapOut` is a better variable name than `fart`.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.println(wordArray)` is going to call `.toString()` on your `ArrayList`, which gives you information about the reference, but not the data inside the list. You need to write out **each element in the list** rather than the list object itself:

```
System.out.println("Words in the array:");
for (String eachWord : wordArray) {
  System.out.println(eachWord);
}
```

---

Now, this only works if you've properly defined your list to be a list of Strings. This definition creates a list of any Java object:

```
ArrayList wordArray = new ArrayList();
```

It's better practice to specify what type of elements will go in your list. This is done by using Generics:

```
ArrayList<String> wordArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

That assumes that your `wordArray` is actually a list of words, but your code adds an **entire array** to the `wordArray` list. What does that give you? I think you want this:

```
while((input=br.readLine())!=null){
    stringArray = input.split(" ");
    // Add each word, not the array
    wordArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
}
```

---

Your problem with words not getting removed is a similar problem. Your ArrayList holds an array of Strings, but you're trying to remove a single String. The call to `.remove()` will not find a String in your ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to evaluate a condition twice.

Replace

```
    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[1])){
        [...]
    }
    if(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[1])){
        [...]
    }
```

with

```
    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[1])) {
        [...]
    } else {
        [...]
    }
```

If you compare a variable with multiple different constants use "else if" (answer can never be "escape" and "print" at the same time). And change the order to avoid Nullpointer exceptions:

```
if("escape".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
    [...]
} else if("print".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `wordArray.remove(stringArray[1]);`

`wordarray` is an array of string arrays.

So change that line to `wordArray.remove(stringArray)`